# Error during save data in database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem when I save data in SQL Server 2008 R2 database using Windows Forms application in C#. My code in the save button is right, but when I click on this button, a messagebox appears

> Invalid column name "CompanyID"...and other columns

but the column does exist in the database table.

My code is

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.ConnectionStr);
string sqltext = "insert into MVConsumingMaker ( [CompanyID] , [MakerID] , [Hour] , [Amount] , [Date] ) values(" + Convert.ToString(CmpCompany.ValueMember) + "," + Convert.ToString(CmpMaker.ValueMember) + "," + CmpHour.Text + "," + TxtAmount.Text + ",'" + MaskDate.Text + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqltext, con);

con.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

TxtResultSave.Text = "the opiration was completed successfully";
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong!

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first **MAJOR** problem is the fact you're using string concatenation to build your SQL statement - this is really bad since you're opening up your code to **SQL injection** - don't do it - **NEVER!**. The only proper way to solve this issue is to **ALWAYS** use **parametrized queries** - define your SQL statement, and whereever you want to "insert" some value, have a `@parameter` so you can set its value properly and safely from your code.

Using parameters also saves you from having to deal with thorny issues like having the right number of quotes and double quotes in your SQL statement, and it allows for more error control since a parameter is assigned a data type, and if the value you're trying to set doesn't match, you'll get a nice proper error message.

Also: you should try to separate your data access logic from the UI logic - don't write all your database code in the middle of a UI event handler. Separate those out - much better and cleaner design, allows you to reuse code and improves overall maintainability of your code base.

So I would write a method something like:

```
public void SaveData(int companyID, int makerID, int hour, decimal amount, DateTime date)
{
    // define your SQL statement using *parameters*
    string sqltext = "INSERT INTO dbo.MVConsumingMaker([CompanyID], [MakerID], [Hour], [Amount], [Date]) " +
                     "VALUES(@CompanyID, @MakerID, @Hour, @Amount, @Date)";

    // put your disposable ADO.NET objects into "using" blocks to ensure proper disposal
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.ConnectionStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqltext, con))
    {
        // define parameters and their values
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = companyID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MakerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = makerID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hour", SqlDbType.Int).Value = hour;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = amount;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;

        // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

and then have my event handler call that method:

```
try
{
    // call the "SaveData" method to actually save the data from the UI elements
    SaveData(Convert.ToString(CmpCompany.ValueMember), 
             Convert.ToString(CmpMaker.ValueMember), 
             CmpHour.Text, TxtAmount.Text, MaskDate.Text);

    // set result text here - in the UI event handler
    TxtResultSave.Text = "The data was successfully saved!";
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
   // handle and/or log exception as needed
   TxtResultSave.Text = "The data was *NOT* successfully saved";
}
```